# set Mask для ui:text webix

Tags: webix, mask

пытаюсь дать маску для   `view: "text"` в *webix*

```
{
   view: "text",
   label: 'Телефон',
   width: 360,
   placeholder: "Телефон",
   name: "telephone"
},
{
  view: "button",
  value: "Закрыть",
  width: 200,
  click: function () {     
         $$("registrationForm").elements["telephone"].mask("(999) 999-9999");                                                              
  }
},
```

пробывал так пишет что mask не функция что я упустил ?

Comment: нужно больше кода

Comment: Откуда у ui.text взялся метод mask?

Comment: это метод jquery я его подключил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В webix версии 3.4 у `view: "text"` появилось свойство pattern.
Если вы используете последнюю версию webix, то во `view: "text"` нужно добавить следующее:

```
pattern:{ mask:"(###) ###-####",   allow:/[0-9]/g }
```

Пример: http://webix.com/snippet/a15991a5

Comment: не работает последняя версия webix -a

Comment: Если нет возможности использовать версию webix 3.4, то можно сделать через метод validate у `view: "form"`, например, вот так:
http://webix.com/snippet/6a4c5ee6. Правило валидации немного поправить нужно, но смысл ясен

Answer (score 2):

Это не будет хорошо работать, webix api предоставляет абстракцию виджета. jquery работает через DOM напрямую. Вы можете выдрать DOM узел, но это костыль. Используйте средства валидации webix.